# Is it necessary to lemmatize the text and remove stopwords for NER?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I'm working on the project where there are several paragraphs of text in which I must extract certain entities using NER. (I'm using **SPACY**)

Here is the sample data:

```
Mr XYZ, XX year old, who was the victim of motor vehicle accident that 
occurred on XX-XX-XX date, he sustained numerous injuries. 
He has been seen in the hospital for the left shoulder and low-back.
```

I must Extract bodypart for which he is being treated, i.e left shoulder & low-back and accident date.
Now if I lemmatize this text the meaning of "left shoulder" changes as "leave shoulder". And if I remove stop words, the bodypart "low-back" will not be recognised as entity as "back" will be removed by stopwords the meaning of entire text changes.
I know that certain stopwords can be removed, but what if other words having importance is removed.
I'm not sure whether stopwords & lemmation is helping me.

Is is ok if I dont do text pre-processing ? or should I proceed with the same?

Comment: Try and see what happens with lemmatize on and off. Consider embedding the n words to the left and right of the current anchor to help capture cases like this.

Comment: I do not think removing stopwords in your case will be beneficial. You should use NER in conjunction with POS.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Raqib. Can you please provide any links or references on how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think these techniques in your case will be beneficial

consider using better NER models with contextual word embeddings such as BERT:

http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp

https://huggingface.co/models

also for training you can use back-translation to increase your training data(it can be done automatically with translating it into Arabic, then translating it back into English)